# What are the differences between Oracle UCM and Oracle Content Server?

Tags: oracle

Whenever I do searches on them, I keep seeing them in search results together.

- What are the differences between Oracle UCM and Oracle Content Server?
- Are they just two names for the same thing?
- Is one a subset of the other?

Answer (score 2):

found partial answer to this . one is a subset of the other .

" Oracle UCM is a suite of enterprise content management products that include Oracle Content Server and Oracle Site Studio. "

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/ucm_adapter/intro.html

still not sure the differences .